# исправить код jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

здравствйте, использую плагин inputmask-master для маски телефонов,все работает отлично, только плагин в поле маску добавляет сразу после загрузки страницы, и если не вводить никакого номера то сохраняется маска а этого же не должно быть! помогите исправить так чтоб маска показывалась только при фокусе на input и при потери фокуса было пустое поле

```
$(function()
{
$(document).on('click', '.btn-addPhone', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var controlForm = $('.controlsPhone:first'),
        currentEntry = $(this).parents('.entryPhone:first'),
        newEntry = $(currentEntry.clone()).appendTo(controlForm);

    newEntry.find('input').val('');
    controlForm.find('.entryPhone:not(:last) .btn-addPhone')
        .removeClass('btn-addPhone').addClass('btn-removePhone')
        .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
        .html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-</span>');

    $('.customer_phone').on('focus', function () {
        inputmasks($.extend(true, {}, maskOpts, {
            list: listCountries,
            onMaskChange: maskChangeWorld
        }));
    });

}).on('click', '.btn-removePhone', function(e)
{
    $(this).parents('.entryPhone:first').remove();

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
});

<div class="controlsPhone">
                    <div class="entryPhone input-group col-xs-3">
                        <input class="form-control customer_phone" name="fields[]"value="" type="text" placeholder="Type something" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-addPhone" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Принципиально этот плагин?

Comment: больше да чем нет, потому что я не нашел более нужного мне решения )

Comment: я пользовался им, но меня не устраивает, у меня номера телефонов всегда разные, разных стран, и соответственно маски разные, а я не хочу дописывать маски в ручную в зависимости от выбраной страны, а этот плагин сам определяет странц и выбирает маску по коду страны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте стандартный настройки плагина "**inputmask-master**"